# IF current year - Degree Year < 7 print Y else print N

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is my code. I'm trying to create a column that will take the current year subtract it from the PI.Degree Year column then determine if it is less than 7. If it is less than 7, print Y. If not, print N.

What am I doing wrong?

```sql
IF (YEAR(NOW()) - ["PI"."Degree Year"]) < 7, 'Y', 'N') AS RESULT
```

Error message:

> Invalid Alias Format : Table_name.Column_name required.

Database system = Oracle

Comment: well that is not oracle

Comment: Use a [CASE Expression](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm) (inside a SELECT command).

Answer (score 1):

The WITH clause is here just to generate some sample data and, as such, it is not a part of the answer.
You can use CASE expression like below to get what you asked for. Keep in mind that multiple (WHEN) conditions within CASE are processed sequentially end the first one that is True will return it's THEN part **and EXIT the CASE.**
This works on all versions of Oracle. Regards...

```sql
WITH 
    tbl AS
        (
            SELECT 2012 "DEGREE_YEAR" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 2015 "DEGREE_YEAR" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 2018 "DEGREE_YEAR" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 2021 "DEGREE_YEAR" FROM DUAL
        )
SELECT
    To_Number(To_Char(SYSDATE, 'yyyy')) "CURRENT_YEAR",
    DEGREE_YEAR "DEGREE_YEAR",
    To_Number(To_Char(SYSDATE, 'yyyy')) - DEGREE_YEAR "YEARS_DIFF",
    CASE 
        WHEN To_Number(To_Char(SYSDATE, 'yyyy')) - DEGREE_YEAR < 7 THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
    END "DIFF_LESS_THAN_7"
FROM
    tbl
--  
--  R e s u l t
--  
--  CURRENT_YEAR DEGREE_YEAR YEARS_DIFF DIFF_LESS_THAN_7
--  ------------ ----------- ---------- ----------------
--          2022        2012         10 N                
--          2022        2015          7 N                
--          2022        2018          4 Y                
--          2022        2021          1 Y
```

More about CASE at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm

Comment: you are assuming that there ie a 4 digit value for year. My solution below I assume DATE and extract the value and avoid to_number and to_chsr and can be used on any date column if needed

Answer (score 0):

You can CREATE a generic function and pass a date from any table. Below is a sample. Note I use the Oracle extract command to pull the year from the date.

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY';

CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME ( test_date) AS
SELECT  DATE '2001-04-03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  DATE '2021-05-23' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  DATE '2011-11-11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  DATE '2022-07-31' FROM DUAL;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_year
(p_date DATE) RETURN VARCHAR2 DETERMINISTIC 
IS
 pragma udf;
 CURRENT_YEAR NUMBER;
 TEST_YEAR NUMBER;
  ANSWER VARCHAR2(1) := 'N';
BEGIN

   CURRENT_YEAR  := EXTRACT( Year FROM SYSDATE);  

   TEST_YEAR := EXTRACT( Year FROM p_date);    

   IF CURRENT_YEAR - TEST_YEAR < 7 
   THEN
     ANSWER := 'Y';
   END IF;

   RETURN ANSWER;
END;
/

SELECT 
   TEST_DATE
   ,TEST_YEAR(TEST_DATE) YN
FROM TABLE_NAME;

TEST_DATE    YN
03-APR-2001    N
23-MAY-2021    Y
11-NOV-2011    N
31-JUL-2022    Y
```